# Translation for "show off"

Tags: english-to-german

I try to find a colloquial way to express "to show off" but I really have no clue among all these possibilieties which one to choose. 
I actually think I just heard "mit (etwas)angeben" ..
What would you say is the best way to say that?

Something that would work in sentences like that: 
"She likes to show off her jewellery"
"Oh, come on man! Stop showing off!" (funny)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary extract you posted is actually quite good. Most of the given translations work, their meaning is quite different, though.

> She likes to show off her jewelry.

Would translate to any of the following:

> Sie gibt mit ihren Juwelen an. (Emphasizes that she has precious jewelry and others don't)
>
> Sie posiert mit ihren Juwelen. (Emphasizes on the presentation aspect)
>
> Sie zeigt ihre Juwelen stolz vor. (She is proud about the jewelry).
>
> Sie prahlt mit ihren Juwelen. (Negative aspect: She is trying to envy others) etc...

So it really depends on what exactly you want to express when choosing the correct expression. Maybe you provide your real example?

Comment: "come on man! Stop showing off!"
This would be the sentence I am mostly interested in

Comment: @E.V.: That would be: "Oh Mann, hör' auf anzugeben!"

Comment: Another variant which emphasizes the "I'm wealthy" aspect is "protzen".

Answer (score 6):

You heard right, as a native speaker I'd say:

1. a show off (noun): Angeber
2. to show off (verb): angeben
3. to show off sth.: mit etwas angeben

The other translations you found are not *wrong*, but more matching to special cases.

Comment: I would possibly add "prahlen" to the more common ones - although it would be a bit more formal to my ears. In the Rheinland I've heard people use it in everyday speech, however.

Comment: @Gerhard: Geht "prahlen" nicht ein wenig in die Richtung, dass der Gegenstand des Angebens explizit beschrieben wird? Meinem Eindruck nach kann man zum Beispiel damit *angeben*, toll Geige spielen zu können, indem man einfach bei jeder Gelegenheit Geige spielt, auch ohne ein Wort zu sagen. Mit dieser Fertigkeit *prahlen* kann man aber nur, indem man explizit durch Worte darauf hinweist, dass man es besonders gut kann.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Würde ich auch so sehen. "Angeben" kann man nur mit etwas, das man wirklich hat und vorzeigen kann. "Prahlen" kann man unter Umständen auch mit etwas völlig unzutreffendem.